# Vitamio on Android 7.0 - Detected problems with app native libraries

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, vitamio

Android app gives the alert on the top of playing video with vitamio

```
Vitamio on Android 7.0 - Detected problems with app native libraries, 
libffmpeg.so: text relocations
```

I'm using latest version of vitamio

```
compile 'com.charonchui.vitamio:vitamio:4.2.2'
```

and simple code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setImmersiveFullScreen();
    if (!io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
        return;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String URL = "ANY URL HERE";
    final VideoView mVideoView = (VideoView) 
    findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

    HashMap<String, String> options;
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(URL));
    mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mVideoView.start();

    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new 
        MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
        }
    });

}
```

It gives this alert and then continues to play video perfectly, but I can't find a way to disable this alert and get this app in production.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does this error popup when you work with a release build ? Because I see the alert once when debugging, but not at all when installing and running release build. Apparently, the shared NDK libraries is the cause of this issue. [See here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0-changes.html#ndk)

Comment: yes this pops up in release build also